# Python: Sum up list of objects

Tags: python

I am working with a number of custom classes `X` that have `__add__(self)`, and when added together return another class, `Y`.

I often have iterables [of various sizes] of `X`, `ex = [X1, X2, X3]` that I would love to add together to get `Y`.    However, `sum(ex)` throws an `int` error, because `sum` starts at 0 which can't be added to my class `X`.

Can someone please help me with an easy, pythonic way to do `X1 + X2 + X3 ...` of an interable, so I get `Y`...

Thanks!

Ps it’s a 3rd party class, X, so I can’t change it.  It does have *radd* though.

My gut was that there was some way to do list comprehension?  Like += on themselves

Comment: Does `X` have an `__radd__()` method?

Comment: Can you post your class code here please?

Comment: Have you tried adding start=X0? Assuming there's a suitable equivalent to zero using X?

Comment: 3rd party package - otherwise I would.   It does have _radd_

Comment: Does class Y have an `__add__` function that accepts an X as argument?

Comment: I don't think this is possible for a generic solution. There is no defined behavior for adding more than two `X` objects together. What is the library? There might be another way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the starting point for a `sum` by passing it as a parameter. For example, `sum([1,2,3], 10)` produces 16 (10 + 1 + 2 + 3), and `sum([[1], [2], [3]], [])` produces [1,2,3].

So if you pass an appropriate ("zero-like") X object as the second parameter to your `sum`, ie `sum([x1, x2, x3,...], x0)` you should get the results you're looking for

Some example code, per request. Given the following definitions:

```
class X:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    def __init__(self, val):                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        self.val = val                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    def __add__(self, other):
        return X(self.val + other.val)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    def __repr__(self):                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        return "X({})".format(self.val)                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
class Y:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    def __init__(self, val):                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        self.val = val                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    def __add__(self, other):
        return X(self.val + other.val)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    def __repr__(self):                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        return "Y({})".format(self.val)
```

I get the following results:

```
>>> sum([Y(1), Y(2), Y(3)], Y(0))
X(6)
>>> sum([Y(1), Y(2), Y(3)], Y(0))
X(6)
>>>
```

(note that Y returns an X object - but that the two objects' **add** methods are compatible, which may not be the case in the OP's situation)

Comment: Can you provide some code? I'm trying this solution and it appears to not work.

Comment: @MichaelM, can you say more about "doesn't work"? I'd be happy to try to sort out the issue, if I knew what question I was answering.

Comment: For this response, I can’t edit the X class though. It’s a 3rd party thing

Comment: Your examples aren't equivalent to their case, since adding ints results in an int and adding lists results in a list. Not like their adding Xs resulting in a Y.

Comment: @MichaelM. : this error shows if you don't explicitly provide a starting object, since start defaults to 0.

Comment: @Swifty No, I did provide a start. It is because 2 `X` classes return a different class, not another `X`.

Comment: Oh, right, I see; then it can't add more than 2 objects! That's actually the common behavior of external operations, like scalar product.

Comment: @Swifty Note it's `__add__(self)`, not `__add__(self, other)`, so apparently it can't even add two.

Comment: Thanks @KellyBundy. It seems OP's question anyway is irrelevant, unless X+Y is defined too (and returns either an X or an Y).

Comment: @JonKiparsky Your edit doesn't help. It assumes that `X` can also be added together, which OP never stated.

Comment: @MichaelM added some examples, hope that helps

Comment: If addition of X and Y are not defined, then we're going to need a little more information - for example, what the OP expects to happen when adding an X to a Y

Comment: @Swifty Yeah, OP should clarify / provide an MRE, and there shouldn't be answers before that happens.

Comment: Furthermore, even if X+Y and Y+Y are defined, we're in for a whole bucket of fun for expressions like X1 + X2 + X3 + X4: are they meant to be computed from left to right, do this return the same value as (X1 + X2) + (X3 + X4)... Reminds me of my algebra classes :)

Comment: @JonKiparsky I have used this a ton - thanks so much for this

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you can add an X to a Y (i.e. `__add__` is defined for Y and accepts an object of class X), then you can use
`reduce` from `functools`, a generic way to apply an operation to a number of objects, either with or without a start value.

```
from functools import reduce

xes = [x1, x2, x3]
y = reduce(lambda a,b: a+b, xes)
```

Comment: This won't work because the `__add__()` function OP asks about doesn't return the same class.

Comment: I was assuming that Y + X is also defined, otherwise the chain operation x1 + x2 + x3 does not make sense.

Answer (score -1):

What if you did something like:

```
Y = [ex[0]=+X for x in ex[1:]][0]
```

I haven’t tested it yet though, on mobile

Comment: Would love to know why -1, does it not work?